# How get the same context in wrapped function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wrapper

In the example, the wrapped function `one_func()` does not "see" sibling function `another_func()` in Python

```py
def wrap_func(call_func):
    call_func()
    print('end')


@wrap_func
def one_func():
    print(123)
    # >>> no such function here
    another_func()


def another_func():
    print(555)


one_func()
```

Actual output:

```
$ python test_wrap.py
123
[...]
NameError: name 'another_func' is not defined
```

How to make a wrapped function "to see" other functions in the same area?

It's expected to have the following output:

```
$ python test_wrap.py
123
555
end
```

P.S. Yes, we may put `another_func()` under `one_func()` but it does not work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your decorator isn't a decorator. It's not returning a decorated function, it's instead immediately calling `one_func`, **at a time when `another_func` hasn't been defined yet.**

Make it a proper decorator:

```
def wrap_func(call_func):
    def wrapper():
        call_func()
        print('end')

    return wrapper
```